# GAC issue cant host application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I’m getting the following error when running my MVC 4 application on IIS 7.5. However, when I run this application via visual studio it does not throw the error. Also, I’ve tried hosting the application in my Uni computer it seems to work fine.

```
  Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>' exists in   both      'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
```

Here are the assemblies referenced in my web.config file

```
     <system.web>
         <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />              
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />               
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>      
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Do you have `System.Web.Mvc` assembly in application bin folder? If so try removing

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

from web.config.

Comment: Perfect! Removed it from Web.config and added the proper assembly as a Reference in the project. Worked like a charm!

Comment: you save my time ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It did not solve my problem, but as it turned out, changing version to 3.0.0.1 did:

`<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

And:

`<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <applicationSettings>`